# Allow user to set schedule for worker to complete assignnment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, schedule

I have an app that allows admins to create assignments and assign to workers on an account. This aspect works great but I'm trying to add a way for admins to set a schedule for when these assignments should be done. Things like how often(weekly, monthly, etc...) and how long the assignment should take (hours or mins). I started a little bit of this build out. Basically I set the attributes on assignment to include `start_at` `end_at` and `frequency`. I'm not sure what to do with these attributes though. Has anybody built a system like this before? What are good gems or libraries I could use to help with this? Here is my schema for assignments:

### Schema:

```
  create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "attachment"
    t.boolean  "finished",       default: false
    t.integer  "finished_count"
    t.boolean  "in_progress",    default: false
    t.datetime "start_at"
    t.datetime "end_at"
    t.string   "frequency"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is actually pretty good. That's what I would do. I would probably make the `frequency` an enumerated type to include only certain values like: 'hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly,' etc. This is easily accomplished by adding the following line to your model class in assignment.rb:

```
enum frequency: [ :hourly, :daily, :weekly, :monthly, :yearly ]
```

The way you've defined `start_at` and `end_at` is fine. Whenever the user accesses their assignment, you simply need to perform a query on the assignment to determine if it is in progress, past due, or not yet open.

Also, it looks like you're storing two boolean values called 'finished' and 'in_progress'. I would probably simplify those fields by creating another enumerated type called 'status' defined as follows:

```
enum status: [ :not_started, :in_progress, :finished ]
```

You'd need to remove the 'finished' and 'in_progress' columns from the table as well as add a field called 'title'. Create a migration file and paste the following code to modify the table:

```
def change
  remove_column :assignments, :finished
  remove_column :assignments, :in_progress
  add_column :assignments, :status, :integer, default: 0

  add_index :assignments, :status
end
```

That's what I would do, but that's just my opinion :) You'll need to code up how to determine whether an assignment is in progress or not by comparing the start and end times.

Comment: Don't forget to add indices to any columns you'll be searching on. This probably means adding indices to account_id and both enums. Though this depends on the exact operations your app does.

Comment: good point @Glyoko I've updated my answer to add an index on the column I recommended adding.